# Where to put frontend `require` files in a Volt project

Tags: ruby, voltrb, opalrb

I'm writing an app that requires me to define a Ruby class outside of the controller, and then instantiate it within a controller.

I put it in `lib/my_file.rb` and also `initializers/client/my_file.rb` and got the same result:

`Sprockets::FileNotFound at /
couldn't find file 'client/my_file' with type 'application/javascript'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by doing this in `main/config/initializers`:

`if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'opal'
      require_relative 'client/my_file'
    else
    end`